# Rewrite database value php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with rewriting a database value.

I have a the following code:

```
<div>
    Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>.
    You are logged in.
</div>

<div>
    Your saved channel is <?php echo $_SESSION['user_channel']; ?>.
</div>

<form method="post" action="rewrite.php">
<select name="user_channel" id="user_channel">
    <option value="NOS">NOS</option>
    <option value="NU">NU</option>
    <option value="RTL">RTL</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

All this is no problem. It shows the username ('user_name') and ('user_channel') from the database in the div tags.

The idea is that the user chooses an option from the select tag and through 'rewrite.php' it will rewrite this 'user_channel' in the database.

**The rewrite.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("db_host","db_name","db_pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("m1_ac082e9d", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO users (user_channel)
VALUES
('$_POST[user_channel]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

When I write something it will make a new table instead of rewriting this users channel.

Any idea anybody?

Comment: Where is the code for rewrite.php?

Comment: your code that performs the write to the table is what is likely the problem, and it happens to be the code that is not shown. mind sharing it?

Comment: I updated the comment with the PHP

Comment: you are looking to `UPDATE` a users entry ... and you are using an `INSERT` statement ... something isn't right here ...

Comment: `... it will make a new table instead of rewriting this users channel.` - Are you saying it is **creating** a table in your MySQL database??

Comment: @scrowler, OP says `table` for `row`. Lapsus.

Comment: So if I replace INSERT with UPDATE it would do the trick?

Comment: The code is open to SQL injection. Also use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql_'. google mysql update

Comment: What is the error you're getting btw ?? Could you able to connect to database in this file ??

Comment: @Sathish Ravepati I am not getting an error, just an extra databasetable instead of rewriting the specific table.

Comment: Does anbody maybe feel like showing me a code. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @Joep - the reason we ask these questions is because we need to know the specific problem before we provide a specific answer. The result of our work will only be as good as the source material.

Comment: I take it you have `session_start();` somewhere? @Joep

Comment: Yes I do have the session_start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you use an `UPDATE` statement instead of your weird `INSERT INTO` statement (which is likely creating a new table, btw):

```
$user = $_POST['user_name'];
$channel = $_POST['user_channel'];

"UPDATE users SET user_channel = '$channel' WHERE user_name = '$user';"
```

Or something along those lines.

Also, please, please, **PLEASE** update your code to use MySQLi. The use of `mysql_` syntax is deprecated due to inherent security flaws that leave your code open to dangerous happenings. Something like this is vastly more secure:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('db_host', 'db_name', 'db_pass', 'm1_ac082e9d');

$stmt = "UPDATE users SET user_channel = ? WHERE user_name = ?;"
if(mysqli_prepare($link,$stmt)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $channel, $user);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Use of the mysqli syntax is key to resolving more recent security holes, and bound statements really make your statement bulletproof from SQL injection. More information can be [found in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), bind param is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the warning! I will try to figure it out. Let's say I am new in this field…

Comment: no worries, i just updated my answer to include an example of what you could do with MySQLi syntax. you need to install the driver (usually u can set it up as a Perl module, commonly available with any host) but it really is the way to build these kinds of queries going forward.

Comment: hey, if it solved ur issue, don't thank me, thank the checkmark. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it works…

I did this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$channel = $_POST['user_channel'];
mysqli_query($db_connection,"UPDATE users SET user_channel='$channel' WHERE user_name='$user'");
$_SESSION['user_channel'] = $channel;
}
?>

<div>
    Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>.
    You are logged in.
</div>
<div>
    Your choosen channel is <?php echo $_SESSION['user_channel']; ?>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>
</div>


<form method="post">
<select name="user_channel" id="user_channel">
    <option value="NOS">NOS</option>
    <option value="NU">NU</option>
    <option value="RTL">RTL</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bewaar">
</form>
```